# Show and hide on focus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have certain input boxes that i want a message to appear under the input box only when it is selected to put in information. not all my input boxes just a few. I have only been able to get errors to work but lets say a user selects the username box i want a message to show under it that says username must contain no characters then when they leave it hides.

this is an example select the username field https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="field-help"> Choose a username that contains only letters and numbers, or use your email address. </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more than one `form-control` you need something like this:

**EDIT:**
replaced show() with slideDown() and hide() with slideUp()

```js
jQuery(function($) {
$('.form-control')
    //.on('focus', function() { $(this).siblings('.field-help').show(); })
    .on('focus', function() { $(this).siblings('.field-help').slideDown(); })
    //.on('blur', function() { $(this).siblings('.field-help').hide() })
    .on('blur', function() { $(this).siblings('.field-help').slideUp() })
    // initialize the hidden state at program start
    .siblings('.field-help').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="field-help"> Choose a username that contains only letters and numbers, or use your email address. </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
    <div class="field-help"> It's allways good to have one. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to put a transition on it?

Comment: Yes, simply replace show() with fadeIn() or slideDown() and hide() with fadeOut() or slideUp(). You can find the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery here

```
<script>
$(".form-control").hover(
 function() {
  $('.field-help').show();
 }, function() {
  $('.field-help').hide();
}
);
</script>
```